version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found after Update Debian 10 to Debian 12
I was instructed to upgrade Debian 10 to Debian 12. After the upgrade, I noticed that the ssh.service was not working. Now I found out that no 'apt' commands work. I can't install anything.
Here the result of the perl -v command:
perl:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by perl)

and
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.28.so

The apt --fix-broken install command also does not work
Edit:
This is my /etc/apt/sources.list file:
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main
This is a good way?
Please help and best regards

You need to upgrade libcrypt1. Since apt doesn’t work, try
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxcrypt/libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcrypt1_4.4.33-2_amd64.deb

If wget doesn’t work, download the file on another computer, and copy it to the broken system.
I’m guessing you tried to upgrade directly from Debian 10 to 12; that’s not supported, you need to upgrade to 11 first. (It’s too late for you now, you need to finish the upgrade to 12.)

wget worked. The file downloaded and installed. However, I don't see, any improvement for the better. Still the same errors.

OK, I thought this was an instance of this known issue when upgrading from 10 to 12. Could you update your question to show the output of ldd /usr/bin/apt?
